# API permission check on CiviVolunteer

Tags: civivolunteer

I created a new CiviVolunteer project and have several successful sign-ups, but one volunteer reported getting this error:

"API permission check failed for VolunteerUtil/getbeneficiaries call; insufficient permission: require edit own volunteer projects"

The successful sign-ups are a mix of named users and anonymous users. The failed sign-up is an anonymous user. This person has successfully signed up for previous projects. I have not changed permission settings recently and have not experienced this error on earlier projects.

I didn't have any issues creating or editing it as admin, but I noticed I get this same error as admin on both the Wordpress and Drupal sandboxes by simply selecting "Manage Volunteer Projects":

https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fvol%2F#/volunteer/manage

https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/manage

My system:
Wordpress 5.2.3
CiviCRM 5.18.1
CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1
PHP 7.2.21
MySQL 5.7.23